# Discord.py, If message length is bigger than a specific number, break it into several lines

Tags: discord.py

I need help.
If the message is longer than a specific number
I want the message breaks into several lines

Example:

```
Displayed Message:
Hello everyone!, I'm AHMED, how are you guys? what are you doing?

Edit:
Hello everyone!, I'm AHMED,
how are you guys? what are you doing?
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Will this message be sent by the bot? Do you want to edit the bot's message? Try to add a little bit more details of what you want to do with this message, then I can find a solution that works best in your case.

Comment: i want the bot to resend the message, but edit it with some edits
1. if the message length is bigger than 45 digits, he goes 1 line below
2. if the message digits is bigger than a 90, he stops at digit 90 and types ".."

Comment: The problem is that if you always go 1 line below after 45 digits you might split the word in some cases. Do you want to always split after 45 digits or around 45 digits, but keep the words together rather than splitting them?

Comment: no, it's okay, it's just a profile title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this one. I used [`strip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) to make sure there won't be any blank characters at the start of a new line.

```py
sentence = "Hello everyone!, I'm AHMED, how are you guys? what are you doing?"
edited = sentence

if len(sentence) > 90:
    edited = sentence[:90].strip() + "..."

elif len(sentence) > 45:
    edited = sentence[:45] + "\n" + sentence[45:].strip()

print(edited)
```

Output:

```
Hello everyone!, I'm AHMED, how are you guys?
what are you doing?
```

Answer (score 0):

use \n to break the lines hope it helps you.